# In which Ravenloft domain does the "Tapestry of Dark Souls" take place?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, ravenloft

There is a Ravenloft novel written by Elaine Bergstrom titled "Tapestry of Dark Souls".  I am wondering in which realm of the Domains of Dread this book is supposed to take place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Markovia and Tepest

The book mentions the Monastic Order of the Guardians. That order is only present in Barovia, Hazlan, Markovia, Mordent, Sithicus, and Tepest.

The Husband and Wife couple, Vhar and Leith, are storied to arrive in Markovia and stealing the Tapestry. Then they both return to Tepest.